# Am I saving processor time by binding an `on` call to something more specific?

Tags: jquery

Looking for a best practice here. But I just recently upgraded an app from jQuery 1.4 to 1.8 and I'm slowly switching out all the `live` calls to `on` calls.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.edit', function(){
```

from :

```
$("a.edit").live(function() {
```

1. Would it be faster to bind it to something more specific other than document?
2. Is there a speed difference between these two calls as is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegating events to the document now means that all elements inside the document when clicked will fire the event handler, and then it checks to see if the target matches `a.edit`, and that's a lot of checking. Narrowing it down to an element closer to `a.edit` will mean less elements fire the event handler, and fewer elements to check for a match with the specified target.

From the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/) :

> Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later
>   versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its
>   drawbacks. In particular, the following issues arise with the use of
>   .live():
>
> jQuery attempts to retrieve the elements specified by the selector
>   before calling the .live() method, which may be time-consuming on
>   large documents. Chaining methods is not supported. For example,
>   $("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... ); is not valid and does
>   not work as expected. Since all .live() events are attached at the
>   document element, events take the longest and slowest possible path
>   before they are handled. Calling event.stopPropagation()  in the event
>   handler is ineffective in stopping event handlers attached lower in
>   the document; the event has already propagated to document. The
>   .live() method interacts with other event methods in ways that can be
>   surprising, e.g., $(document).unbind("click") removes all click
>   handlers attached by any call to .live()!

What it basically does is something like:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == ourElement) {
        //hey, our element was clicked and bubbled all the way to the root, 
        //so let's do something
    }else{
        //we just jumped through some hoops, but this is not the element we 
        //are looking for, so do nothing...and we do this on every click !
    }
});
```

Comment: Would it then by a good idea to assign it to one Div above your choice element? Specifically, what is the best practice in choosing that element that you want the `on` call to bind to if it isn't `document`.

Comment: You assign the handler to the closest element that is not dynamic, or in other words the closest parent that exists at the time you're binding the event so as to narrow the pool of elements that will trigger the event as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

to expand a bit on @adeneo's answer,

```
$(document).on('click','a.edit',function(){...});
```

attaches an event handler to the document. Because `document` is the root of the DOM, every event will eventually bubble up to `document` unless propagation is stopped at some point along the way.

In your example, this means that every single click will trigger your event handler. The handler will then check `event.target` to see if the source of the click matches the provided selector (in this case, `a.edit`). Considering `click` is one of, if not the most common events that occurs on a web page, there will be a lot of processing going on here.

Best practice when delegating events is to select the closest common ancestor among the elements you are targeting with your event handler (obviously, the element must also exist at run-time so the handler can be attached by jQuery). This will minimize the number of times the event handler is fired unnecessarily and ensure that all your target elements are captured with a single call to `.on`

Answer (score 1):

There is no speed difference between the 2 methods, because they both need to check if the clicked element is `a.edit` or not - and that will take the same time.

But there is a difference in number of times the check will be called - if you attach the listener to `document` it will fire on **every** click. Which is much more often if you do it in the other way.

However the key difference (regardless of speed) between

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.edit', function(){
```

and

```
$('a.edit').on('click', function(){
```

is that the first one binds the `click` listener to all existing and **future** elements that you might create later. The second one binds the listener **only** to existing elements.